# Javascript class constructor with parameter used as key from object literal

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, ecmascript-6, object-literal

Title might be a little confusing, but I have following problem:

```
var propertyList = {
    type1: {property1: 1},
    type2: {property1: 2}
}

class Test {
    constructor(typ){
        this.property1 = propertyList.typ.property1;
    }
}

var a = new Test('type1');
```

Code is pretty self-explanatory - I want to set `property1` property of `a` object not by passing value manually in constructor, but rather chosing one of values from `propertyList` object literal by passing one of its key to constructor. I expected that when I run above code, object `a` will be created with `property1` value set to 1. However instead of that I got `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'property1' of undefined` error. When I pust console.log(typ) in the first line of constructor, it correctly shows that value passed into constructor is `type1`. Why above code doesn't work and can it be fixed somehow?

Comment: You need to use this syntax : `propertyList[typ].property1` otherwise it will look for the property name **typ** in the propertyList object (and this property doesn't exist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is a little off. You can't use the passed-in argument `typ` in your assignment like that because the code will then actually look for the property `typ` within `propertyList` (like `propertyList { typ: }`). To use your passed-in argument, wrap it in brackets:

```
this.property1 = propertyList[typ].property1;
```